# Avoid fade-in effect

Tags: winforms, fade, effects

In Vista and higher, a WinForm is faded in by default:
When I show it, it is not "Bamm, here it is", but it has a gentle fade-in by default.
How can I avoid/turn off this fade-in effect per window?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set `Opacity=1` in the constructor? It's only an idea, I didn't try it